How can I write an efficient builder in Rust?
Lets say I want to write a type that builds a fairly large string (lets say of html) then returns it without copying or cloning the string. Is there a way that I can implement an unwrap function that will prevent further access to the builder.
For example this works:
mod test {
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    struct StringBuilder {
        buffer: RefCell<String>,
    }

    impl StringBuilder {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self { buffer: RefCell::new(String::with_capacity(8000)) }
        }

        pub fn append(self: &Self, s: &str) -> &Self {
            self.buffer.borrow_mut().push_str(s);
            self
        }

        pub fn unwrap(self: &Self) -> String {
            self.buffer.borrow().clone()
        }
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn test() {
        let sb = StringBuilder::new();
        sb.append("a").append("b");
        let s = sb.unwrap();
        println!("{s}");
    }
}

But it has to clone the string in the unwrap. I thought about making the unwrap take &mut Self instead of &Self preventing any further references in the calling code, but the mutable reference goes out of scope right away.

If you use self (a value) instead of &self or &mut self (a reference), you will consume the builder.
Why did you choose the name unwrap? It's not familiar in this context.

This is not my actual code, just a trivial example to illustrate, so don't get too hung up on calling it unwrap. Is there a conventional name for a function that drops the data and returns the internal state?

Is there a reason for using a cell? You could simply return the buffer when using a consuming method.

In my actual application it's inconvenient to have a mutable pointer to the builder, because I am passing it through a chain of closures and the borrowing rules get complicated. I realize that there is a small performance penalty for the RefCell, but in this case it's worth it to avoid the &mut.

I would do something like
        pub fn build(self) -> String {
            self.buffer.into_inner()
        }

A value (not a reference) for self consumes the builder.
I would also choose another name than unwrap since in Rust it refers to Option or Result; build seems appropriate for a builder.
See this documentation.

I noticed that the filter builder in warp uses unwrap, and thought that it might be a convention for closing off a sequence of steps. I will rename to build in my application unless there is another prevailing convention.

@bikeman868 Do you refer to this function? If so, look at the return type; it's a Result, hence the .unwrap() operation (in optimistic scenarios).

Yes, I guess the filter can fail to build somehow.

After some more experimenting, it looks like unwrap should be written as
pub fn unwrap(self: Self) -> String {
  self.buffer.take()
}

With this implementation unwrap takes ownership of itself, and drops itself when the unwrap function returns. The take function of RefCell does a similar thing, moving the contents out of the RefCell and returning ownership to caller of unwrap
